# "each light deserting her" or "each light was deserting her"?

Tags: present-participles, participle-phrases

> Her voice compelled me forward breathlessly as I listened -- then the glow faded, each light deserting her with lingering regret like children leaving a pleasant street at dusk".
>    [(*The Great Gatsby*, by F. Scott Fitzgerald)](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/64520-for-a-moment-the-last-sunshine-fell-with-romantic-affection)

Why we didnt use "each light was deserting her" instead of the real sentence?

Comment: Could you link to the source?  Also, have you studied the grammar of the [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm)?

Comment: It's a stylistic choice - and obviously you can take it for granted a writer like F. Scott Fitzgerald would have made *the right choice*. As to the "justification" for choosing to use just a participial phrase rather than a syntactically complete "embedded sentence", there may be no definitive answer. But I suggest that perhaps using the "fully tensed" verb form (***deserted*** or ***was deserting***) would unwantedly focus attention on ***what each light was doing***, where what he wants to focus is ***how the glow faded***.

Answer (score 1):

**Each light was deserting her** is a complete sentence: it has a subject (*each light*) and a verb (*was deserting*).  **Then the glow faded** is also a complete sentence, because it has a subject (*the glow*) and a verb (*faded*).  This is why

> then the glow faded, each light **was** deserting her with lingering regret like children leaving a pleasant street at dusk

is technically incorrect: it is smushing together two complete sentences with only a comma between them, which is an error called a [comma splice](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/).

The way that Fitzgerald wrote it,

> then the glow faded, **each light deserting her** with lingering regret like children leaving a pleasant street at dusk

uses the "each light deserting" part as a [participle phrase](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/), which works like an adjective; it is describing something about how the glow faded.

To explain it by using an analogy, it's like the difference between

> I ate fish thinking about Italy  *(I was thinking about Italy while eating the fish; maybe the fish made me think about Italy)*

and

> I ate fish, I was thinking about Italy *(I performed the two actions separately)*

Comment: I would say—more like an adverb if "it is describing something about **how** the glow faded." Besides, it may be put as _"then the glow faded **with** each light deserting her with lingering regret like children leaving a pleasant street at dusk"_, in which case it would be something I don't know name for (a complement?)

Comment: I agree with you because adjectives are words that describe nouns . In that specific example "each light deserting" is more like an adverb. It is describe the action of fading . By the way if that comment are completely wrong forgive me :)

Comment: Legal language uses this structure all the time with the verb being. The rents shall be paid into a bank account, ***each payment being due on the first of the month***. [sorry, not the greatest example). I dunno what to call it exactly. But this is really; each light [was] deserting her with [rest of sentence].

Comment: There is a technical term for leaving out the was; some kind of catena.